# Grid error for only one record

Tags: struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

I have bug in struts2-grid-Jquery.Every time grid contains only one record ,grid disappear the record as in hyperlink but if there are more than one record it work fine. My code :

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" 
            dataType="json"
            href="%{remoteurl}" 
            gridModel="allCustomerRequests"
            pager="true"
              page="1"
            rowNum="10"
            pagerButtons="true"
                  pagerInput="true"
            gridview="true"
            rowTotal="true" 
            rownumbers="true" 
            rowList="10,20,30,40,40,50,60,70,80,90,100" 
            viewrecords="true"
            autowidth="true" 
            loadonce="true"
            viewrecords="true"
            > 

            <sjg:gridColumn  name="stRefID" formatter="formatViewLink"
                title="%{getText('COMMON_REFERENCE_NUMBER')}"  />

            <sjg:gridColumn name="requestType.stName" 
                title="%{getText('RequestTracking_Request_Type')}" />
            <sjg:gridColumn name="requestStatus.stStatus" 
                title="%{getText('RequestTracking_Request_Status')}" />

            <sjg:gridColumn name="requestStatus.tsDate" 
                          title="%{getText('DATE')}" 
                          formatoptions="{newformat : 'd/m/Y', 
                          srcformat : 'Y-m-d'}"   formatter="date" />


        </sjg:grid>
```

Please help me to solve my bug

[enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=971&thanks=971&ts=1366729966)

Answer (score 1):

I m pretty sure you are expriencing this issue with IE...?

It has nothing to do with the grid plugin but the way IE includes the size of scroll bar when calculating height/width.

A workaround for you is to fix the height of your grid using the `height` attribute of `<sjg:grid />`.